# Creating graph in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, plot

Can I creating graph like this or something like this in Latex?
[image]

Comment: look up the `pgfplots` package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something to start with. Have a look at the [pgfmanual](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), or [a minimal introduction to tikz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) for more details.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \draw [ultra thin, gray] (-1,0) grid [step=1] (4,4);
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};
        
        \draw [thick, red, <->] plot [domain=-1:3] (\x,{(\x-1)^2}) node [above] {$f(x)$};
        \draw [thick, blue, <->] plot [domain=-0.5:1.5] (\x,{(2*\x-1)^2}) node [above] {$f(2x)$};
        
        \draw [->] (2.5,3) -- (1.5,3);
        \draw [->] (-0.8,3.5) -- (-0.5,3.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]